# Haskell - check whether a 2D list has the same number of rows as columns

Tags: arrays, list, haskell, equality

I have a 2D list `[[Int]]` in Haskell and I want to check two things:

1. whether the list has the sam number of rows as columns
2. whether the rows have the sam number of elements

**For instance:**

`[[1,2,3], [1,55,9]]` has the same number of rows as columns - here 2 - and each row has the same number of elements namely 3.

**But**

`[[1,2], [1,55], [4,7]]` has the same number of elements in each row though it has unequal number of rows and columns namely 3r 2c.

**yet another example:**

`[[1,2], [1,55], [4,7,8]]` has neither the same number of rows as columns nor each row has the same number of elements.

Actually step 1 includes step 2, am I right??

**My attempt:**

So what I attempted so far, is this:

```
listIsEqual :: [[Int]] -> Bool
listIsEqual myList = (all (\x -> length x == (length myList)) )
```

Right now I get the following error mesage:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[a0] -> Bool'
In the return type of a call of `all'
Probable cause: `all' is applied to too few arguments
In the expression: (all (\ x -> length x == (length myList)))
In an equation for `listIsEqual':
            listIsEqual myList = (all (\ x -> length x == (length myList)))
```

Could anyone tell me where the problem is?

Is there also any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, if your data's shape is a regular multidimensional array, I think you should try using an array type instead of `[[a]]`; that way the data type can guarantee that the shape is always met. [Look here.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays)

Answer (score 7):

GHC's error messages aren't always the most helpful, but in this case it got it right.

> Probable cause: `all' is applied to too few arguments

And indeed, you forgot the second argument to `all`:

```
listIsEqual myList = all (\x -> length x == length myList) myList
                                                           ^^^^^^
```

Comment: thanks to both for your help. I solved it now in this short function `listIsEqual myList = all (==(length myList)) (map length myList)`. Do you see any issue regarding it?? I'll test your solution also and give feedback about that soon ...

Comment: @John: That's equivalent to my solution. In general, `all p (map f xs) === all (p . f) xs`.

Comment: sorry I hadn't seen it before, because it was so similar to my first attempt and I thought you quoted me ;-) So in my first approach I had the 2nd arg for all forgotten :-(

Answer (score 3):

For the second task, you can map the length of every row (the number of columns in that row) defining a function

```
let columnLengths rows = map length rows
Prelude> columnLengths [[1,2], [1,55], [4,7,8]]
[2,2,3]
```

Now that we have a list containing the lengths of the columns, we have to check whether they are all equal. The function `nub` in `Data.List` removes duplicates from a list.

```
let columnsLengthEqual = (==) 1 . length . nub . columnLengths
```

Or all together

```
let columnsLengthEqual = (==) 1 . length . nub . map length
```

Comment: Quit frankly I'm missing the intention of the task.. aren't they the same? I mean when I solve the first step, I have already solved the 2nd step by that too. So, for me ist the 2nd step a part of the first step. Do I miss something???

Comment: No you didn't miss anything, I did :-)

Answer (score 0):

Matrix respecting your criteria, are  squared matrix then checking if the square of first 's row's length is equal to the number of element should be ok.

```
isSquaredMatrix xs@(h:_)  = ((^2) . length $ h) == (length . concat $ xs) 
isSquaredMatrix _         =  True
```

But as it has been pointed out by hammar, this is incorrect since we can have positive outcome using wrong input.

```
# isSquaredMatrix [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
True -- But this is false
```

---

**@John,**

we use `@` into pattern matching when we want to refer to the whole type at the same time we have break it down. An example should give you more insight,

Usually we can define an exhaustive function working on list using pattern matching as follow.

```
actOnList []     = -- do something when we encounter an empty list
actOnList (x:xs) = -- do something with h, and do another stuff with xs
```

For example,

```
actOnList [] = []
actOnList (x:xs) = 
    if (pred x)
    then x:xs
    else actOnList xs
```

Here my function consumme the list until a predicate is satisfied.
We can imagine skipUntilMeetAChar

```
skipUntilMeetAChar :: [Char] -> Char -> [Char]
skipUntilMeetAChar []  c    = []
skipUntilMeetAChar (x:xs) c = 
    if (x==c)
    then x:xs
    else actOnList xs c
```

As you see when the char is met we'd like to return the list as it, not only the tail, then to do so we need to reconstruct our list using the head `x` and the tail `xs`. This can be overcome using `@`.

```
skipUntilMeetAChar :: String -> Char -> String
skipUntilMeetAChar []  c    = []
skipUntilMeetAChar l@(x:xs) c = 
    if (x==c)
    then l 
    else actOnList xs c
```

Now, regarding ($) operator, this is again some syntactic sugar.
As function application are left associative, this lead us to extensively use bracket to reorder the application of our function, as in the example below.

```
# f3 (f2 (f1 (f0 x)))
```

Then to avoid the pain of managing closing parentheses, dollars operator `$` have been introduce and then our previous expression become.

```
# f3 $ f2 $ f1 $ f0 x
```

Which is definitely more readable and easiest to write.

**Note** that this operator is defined as follow.

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b  
f $ x = f x
```

And I advise you to learn more about it consulting the following [introduction material](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application).

Comment: This approach will give you false positives. For example, it returns true for `[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]`.

Comment: thanks, this seems also to be a nice solution, however I don't know the meaning of @ and $ yet. I'm a newbie ;-)

Comment: @hammar thanks to mention it. I'll update the answer accordingly and take this opportunity to introduce John to pattern matching and ($) operator.

Comment: @zurgl thank you very much indeed for your help. Since I have to do one more Haskell task for my exam tomorrow, I'll try to comprehend your explaination tomorrow after school. I have big trouble with my last taks, which I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426680/haskell-does-a-replace-function-exist It would be very kind if you could help me with that, so that I pass my exam tomorrow. Thanks once again.