# Haskell - Does a replace function exist?

Tags: list, haskell, nested, replace

I have to make three functions for replacing of flat strings and in lists.

I don't know, whether there is a replace function like in other languages. I searched for that however unfortunately without success :-(

So my attempt is yet quite thin.

**1st function:**

```
replace  ::  String  ->  String  ->  String  ->  String
replace findStr replaceStr myText = replace()??
```

**My approach for the 1st function:**

```
replace :: String -> String -> String -> String
replace [] old new = []

replace str old new = loop str
  where
    loop [] = []
    loop str =
      let (prefix, rest) = splitAt n str
      in
        if old == prefix                -- found an occurrence?
        then new ++ loop rest           -- yes: replace

        else head str : loop (tail str) -- no: keep looking
    n = length old
```

**2nd function:**

```
replaceBasedIdx ::  String  ->  [String]  ->  String  ->  String
replaceBasedIdx findStr replaceStrList myText = replace()???
```

This function should replace the 1st findStr in myTxt with the 1st element of replaceStrList, the 2nd findStr with the 2nd element and so on...

**Example:**

```
replaceBasedIdx   "a"  ["G","V","X"]  "Haskell is a language"
"HGskell is V lXnguage"
```

**My approach for the 2nd function:**

```
replaceBasedIdx    ::  String  ->  [String]  ->  String  ->  String
replaceBasedIdx    findStr replaceStrList myText = replaceBasedIdxSub findStr replaceStrList myText 0

replaceBasedIdxSub  ::  String  ->  [String]  ->  String  -> Int -> String
replaceBasedIdxSub findStr replaceStrList myText counter = loop myText
  where
    loop [] = []
    loop myText =
      let (prefix, rest) = splitAt n myText
      in
        if findStr == prefix                                -- found an occurrence?
        then (replaceStrList !! (counter+1)) ++ loop rest   -- yes: replace it

        else head myText : loop (tail myText)               -- no: keep looking
    n = length findStr
```

**I'm now very near to the final result, however the counter doesn't increment.**

Could you please tell me, where my mistake is?
And how could I modifey the 1st or 2nd function to get the 3rd function also?

**3rd function:**

```
replaceBasedIdxMultiple  ::  [String]  ->  [String]  ->  String  ->  String
replaceBasedIdxMultiple  findStrList replaceStrList myText = replace()???
```

This function should replace each element of findStrList in myTxt with the corresponding element from the replaceStrList, so 1. with 1., 2. with 2. and so on...

**Example:**

```
replaceBasedIdxMultiple ["A","X","G"] ["N","Y","K"]  "ABXMG"
"NBYMK"
```

Could you help me with this? some tips and hints, how to begin with it?

I'm really disparate :-(

Thanks a lot in advance

Kind greetings!

Comment: If you want to replace single characters, then `replace` can be written as a `map`.

Comment: I don't really see any "attempt", only type signatures. Have you actually tried to write one of these? It's not _that_ difficult...

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm totaly new to Haskell and I don't know anything about replacing in Haskell. If it was an imperative language like C# or Java or so, it would be very simple, but in Haskell is everything difficult for me. please help, so that I can pass tomorrow my exam :-( **@larsmans** what do you mean bei `map . -`.? Do you have an example for me please?

Comment: for the first function I found this code, I don't understand it completely but I will attempt to comprehend it. However it works just for plain text not for lists. How could I modifie it in order to get it functional for lists too? Isn't it too long and complicated than necessary??

Comment: Can you append that snippet to your _question_? In a comment, without indentation, it's rather unreadable...

Comment: If your exam is tomorrow and you don't even know how to start on this, it's probably too late.

Comment: **@leftaroundabout** ok, it's done. **@C. A. McCann** maybe you are right, but I have to send my solution to the prof. and in one or two weeks we discuss it, so I have time to comprehend it. The problem is that I have tell tomorrow time for sending my paper :-(

Comment: Don't use a _counter_! This is Haskell, not Fortran... Just pop elements off the `replaceStrList`. You still have to call all of `replaceBasedIdxSub` with the modified argument, rather than just loop.

Answer (score 6):

[replace](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-List-Utils.html#v%3areplace) exists in `Data.List.Utils`, part of `MissingH` package.

Actually, it's a really concise implementation:

```
replace :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replace old new = join new . split old
```

Comment: When I attempt to access this library `import Data.List.Utils`. it throws an error ``Could not find module `Data.List.Utils'``. How can I make it it accessable?

Comment: what does it mean? shoul I install something or is it the code? how do I use it, if it's code?

Comment: Cabal is the tool for installing Haskell packages, read more on the wiki: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-install

Comment: ok, the I can't use it unfortunately, because I must work with the standard envoirnment, which we have in the school - but anyway thank you very much for the tip

Comment: You can still look at its source (or even steal the whole thing).

Comment: does it take time or can I install it quick? In your replace code you use `split`. the compiler gives an error Split is not in scope? Where do I get it?

Comment: Ah, unfortunately, they're also both in `MissingH` ([join](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-List-Utils.html#v%3ajoin), [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-List-Utils.html#v%3asplit)). To install the package just try the cabal command on your machine.

Comment: cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal

Answer (score 1):

First off, `join` is a bad name as [that's already a standard function](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=join). Also, I have no idea why you define this function, in this way – it doesn't seem to do anything much useful.

But ok, you did try something. So let's now find a proper solution...

As is usually a good idea in Haskell, we want to break this up into sub-problems. What's first needed is to *find* the sub-strings you'd like to replace. This could look something like

```
locateSub :: (Eq a) =>
        [a]             -- ^ The sought sublist.
     -> [a]             -- ^ The source list.
     -> Maybe ([a],[a]) -- ^ Everything to the left and, if found, everything
                        -- to the right of the sought sublist. No need to return
                        -- the sublist itself in between since we already know it!
```

Using this function, `replace` is straight-forward:

```
replace oldSub newSub list
    = case locateSub oldSub list of
        Nothing -> list   -- Sublist not found: we're done already!
        Just (l, r) -> l ++ newSub ++ replace oldSub newSub r
```

`replaceBasedIdx` isn't much more difficult, you only need to recurse over a list of `newSub`s rather than passing it always as-is.

So what you need to do is implement `locateSub`. With `isPrefixOf` you're already on the right track. Actually it looks a lot like your `_replace` (BTW: it's custumary in Haskell to use the prime `'` rather than underscores to name "local variants / helpers" of a function, so you'd rather call it `replace'`.)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help first! Now I try to use your code and I get an compiling error ``Not in scope: `locateSub'``. Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: No, just as I said: _what you need to do is implement `locateSub`_.

Comment: ok, I tried this but it doesn't work at all
`locateSub :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe ([a], [a])
locateSub oldSub newSub list = map (== oldSub) (tails list)`. I can't comprehend it at all :-( Could you please help me out of the fix? I'll set tomorrow and learn your code...

Comment: `locateSub` doesn't take a `newSub` argument. And using `tails` is in principle a good idea, but it doesn't really work here because it "throws away" the left side, which you need. I think you're better off with manual recursion in this case.

Comment: how about `drop`. in combination with isPrefixOf? Would it work?

Comment: No, for the same reason I just argued against `tails`. You could use `splitAt`, but not in a really simple way. As I said, `locateSub` is something I'd just write by hand as a recursive function.

Comment: now I'm confused, `locateSub 2 or 3 args, right? which are they? I can'T see any data type for the args. All of them are ´[a]´.

Comment: oops, I meant `locateSub`. **takes** 2 or 3 args – what is actualy the return type of `locateSub`.?

Comment: If you can't even read such a simple type signature you're truly in trouble. Hint: you could instantiate it as `locateSub :: String -> String -> Maybe(String, String)`.

Comment: ok I'll try it but now I implemented it in a different way but it doesn't work still s. my question update

Comment: I don't understand, what locateSub should do and return? Could you please explain it to me in words? Does it return the findStr or the position?

Comment: I already explained it in words. — Why would it return the `findStr`? We already know that. It _could_ return the position, but that's quite un-Haskellish and would be inefficient with lists (you know, _O_ (_n_) random access...), so we return the _context_ of the substring instead, i.e. what's left of it and what's right of it – provided the substring can be found at all. If it can't be found, we return `Nothing`, so the return type has to be `Maybe([a], [a])`.

Comment: I can't get it, could you please help me out of the fix?

Comment: Could some one please help me to solve the incrementation issue? Thanks